# Multiple concatenate string acording to parameter in java

Tags: java, string, string-concatenation

I want write to console tree in java in recusive function, one of parameter is depth of tree and I wanna use it for number of tabulators before node names.

```
public void print(TreeNode node, int depth)
//something ...
String prefix =  "";
for(int i = 0; i <depth; i++) {
   prefix += "\t";
}

//....
List<TreeNode> subnodes = node.getNodes();
   for(int i = 0; i < subnodes.size(); i++) {
     System.out.println(prefix+ subnodes.get(i).getTitle()); //title is name of node;
   }
}
```

Is any better solution for string concatenation for prefix then do it by for? 
For example I wanna do 2x "\t" which mean "\t\t" if 2 = depth. If depth is variable I wanna do depth x "\t";
My solution is use for but is there any better for this simple thing?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to change your program in order to use `StringBuilder` class:

```
StringBuilder prefix = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < depth, ++i) {
    prefix.append("\t");
}

....

System.out.println(prefix.toString() + subnodes.get(i).getTitle());
```

`String` in Java is immutable and that's why when you modify it, acually new copy of `String` is created. If your tree is really big and deep (or tall :) - `StringBuilder` should work faster and consume less memory.

If `for` loop is a problem, you may consider such solutions as storing map of depth level -> pre-calculated prefix like this:

```
Map<Integer, String> prefixes = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

private void fillPrefixes(int maxTreeDepth) {
    StringBuilder prefix = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < maxTreeDepth; ++i) {
        prefixes.put(i, prefix.toString());
        prefix.append("\t");
    }
}
```

This may be useful for the cases of huge trees, when you really recalculate that prefix over 9000 times. Technically, `for` loop is still there, but you do not recalculate prefix each time you need it. Another side of the coin is increased memory consumption. So, to make a right decision you need to avoid premature optimizations and do it only when you really need it, and also decide what is more critical - memory or execution time.

Comment: Well this is interesting point and I will probably use it in my actual solution, but my question was actually if is possible get rid of the for.

Comment: I have updated the post with possible tradeoff solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Apache Commons Lang for that.

Maven dependency for it:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
  <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And sample usage:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
...
prefix = StringUtils.repeat("\t", depth);
```